# Image change on click in jquery

Tags: jquery, web

Am using the below code. I have 2 images. Plus and minus. on click of plus the image should change to minus. But here the image is not changing.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plus").click(function () {
        if ($('#divreg').is(":hidden")) {
            $('#divreg').show(500);
            document.getElementById('plus').src = "~/Styles/min.jpg";
        } else {
            $("#divreg").hide(500);
            document.getElementById('plus').src = "~/Styles/plus.jpg";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't you have errors in the console, for example files not found ? Can you build a fiddle showing your problem ?

Comment: i am not sure about `~` will work or not

Comment: Just an aside...You can replace `document.getElementById('plus').src = XXX;` with `$("#plus").attr("src", XXX)` (where XXX is your image source) since you're using jQuery

Comment: @JordanTrudgett But a better solution here would be `this.src=XXX`.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your html via JSFiddle or similar I do see one problem. You are using the server url as:

```
~/Styles/min.jpg
```

This is parsed by the ASP.NET runtime and not by JQuery so your image path is incorrect. Change this path to test it and see if this works. If not, you have other errors and should create a test case for it on JSFiddle to get more help.

Answer (score 0):

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ponrajpaul/BwGTn/

make your html like this

```
<div id="plus">
    <a class="plus minus"></a>    
</div>
```

make your css like this

```
#plus a{display:block; width:128px; height:128px;}
#plus .plus{background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/128/Alarm-Plus-icon.png") no-repeat;}
#plus .minus{display:block; background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/128/Math-minus-icon.png") no-repeat;}
```

make your script like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plus a").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('minus')){  
            $(this).removeClass("minus");              
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("minus");              
        }
    });
});
```